# Display pandas dataframe float values with percentage formatting and format 0 values

Tags: python, pandas

In a Jupyter notebook, I would like to display a pandas dataframe with the following format:

- Percent-style floating values with 2 decimal places
- 0 values are not shown

I tried this:

```
# Float format options 
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.2%}".format

# => I don't know how to not display 0 values.
# I know I could do something like this:
display(df.replace(0, ""))
# but I don't want to modify the dataframe that I think "replace" function does.
```

Can I do this without modifying the dataframe?

Comment: [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) doesn't modify the dataframe unless you specify `inplace=True`

Answer (score 3):

Your approach doesn't modify the DataFrame but creates a copy.

That said, you could use a custom formatting function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1/3], [2/3, 1]])

def custom(s):
    return '' if s==0 else "{:.2%}".format(s)

pd.options.display.float_format = custom

display(df)
```

Output:

```
       0       1
0         33.33%
1 66.67% 100.00%
```

Comment: It works, but it still shows 0 values from "int" columns, can we hide both?

Comment: @nurasaki you have to explicitly convert those columns to float `df.astype(float)` or `df.astype({'your_col': float})`

Comment: No, I don't want to convert "int" columns to "float" because have to remain with their own format (only that I don't want to show 0 values either)

Comment: @nurasaki OK, then in this case you initial approach was fine, you could also use [`style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.style.html)